# Dynamic where clause Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array `brand_ids = [1, 2];`

I want to query the offers table where the brand_id is equal to the values in the array.

```
foreach ($brandIds as $brandId) {
            $where .= "->where('brand_id', {$brandId})";
        }
$query = DB::table('offers')->$where;
$offers = $query->get();
```

This is where my thinking is however the above does not work.

Comment: No, that won't work. To build a dynamic query, you want to create the query first to create a QueryBuilder object, then build on to it. However, your logic won't work because it will become "where brand_id = 1 and brand_id = 2". What you really want is [->whereIn('brand_id', $brand_ids)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put code together in a string and hope it works? You may want to learn the basics of PHP before moving on to building an app with Laravel.

What you probably want to do is use the `Model::whereIn()` method:

```php
$offers = Offers::whereIn("brand_id", $brands)->get();
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `WHERE IN` can be quite slow on MySQL/MariaDB but this is only really a concern when you get into like thousands of records.